# Slightly different alignments of divs simply with different length of paragraphs

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Below there are two webpages. Everything is the same except the length of paragraphs (the p tag). But the two webpages look slightly different (in terms of aligment). 
In other words, the page with fewer paragraphs is aligned **left** compared with the page with more paragraphs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style type="text/css">
    body{
        margin:0 auto;
        font-family:Helvetica Neue, Helvetice-Neue, Helvetica;
        font-weight:200;
        font-size:16px;
        color:#2f2f2f;
    }

    .breakv{
        float:left;
        width:2px;
        height:200px;
        margin-top:78px;
        margin-right:3px;
        padding-top:18px;
        padding-left:2px;
        background:url(images/breakv.png) repeat-y;
    }

    strong{
        color:#0074B4;
    }

    .breakh{
        width:370px;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding-top:8px;
        height:4px;
        background:url(images/breakh.png) bottom repeat-x;
    }

    .navbar{
        background-color:#57b7df;
        font-family:Helvetica Neue, Helvetice-Neue;
        font-weight:100;
        line-height:21px;
        border-color:transparent;
    }

    .carousel-inner > .item > img,
    .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
        width: 50%;
        margin: auto;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="container">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <img src="./images/header.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div style="background-color:#57b7df" class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href=".\index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".\photos.html">Photos</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href=".\prices.html">Prices</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".\instructions.html">Instructions</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".\testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".\contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container-fluid hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <img src="images/prices1.png" class="img-responsive col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            <img src="images/prices3.png" class="img-responsive col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            <img src="images/test3.png" class="img-responsive col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        </div>

        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xl" data-ride="carousel">
            <!- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="images/prices1.png" >
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/prices2.png">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/test3.png">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <h3>Private or Party</h3>
        <p>Do you need a quick tan just for yourself or are you thinking of making it a fun event for you and your friends? <strong>A Kiss of Bronze Airbrush Tanning</strong> offers both personal tanning sessions and tanning parties!</p>
        <p>Never heard of a tanning party? You've heard of lingerie parties, cosmetics parties, jewelry parties, even tupperware parties!!!  Well now it's time to introduce <strong>TANNING PARTIES</strong>!</p>
        <p>You and a minimum of five (5), max of ten (10), friends get together, and you all get tanned in one session.  The hostess of six (6) or more people gets to <strong>tan for free</strong>!</p>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

With more text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <style type="text/css">
        body{
            margin:0 auto;
            font-family:Helvetica Neue, Helvetice-Neue, Helvetica;
            font-weight:200;
            font-size:16px;
            color:#2f2f2f;
        }

        .breakv{
            float:left;
            width:2px;
            height:200px;
            margin-top:78px;
            margin-right:3px;
            padding-top:18px;
            padding-left:2px;
            background:url(images/breakv.png) repeat-y;
        }

        strong{
            color:#0074B4;
        }

        .breakh{
            width:370px;
            margin:0 auto;
            padding-top:8px;
            height:4px;
            background:url(images/breakh.png) bottom repeat-x;
        }

        .navbar{
            background-color:#57b7df;
            font-family:Helvetica Neue, Helvetice-Neue;
            font-weight:100;
            line-height:21px;
            border-color:transparent;
        }

        .carousel-inner > .item > img,
        .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
            width: 50%;
            margin: auto;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body class="container">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <img src="./images/header.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

        <div style="background-color:#57b7df" class="container-fluid">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href=".\index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href=".\photos.html">Photos</a></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href=".\prices.html">Prices</a></li>
                            <li><a href=".\instructions.html">Instructions</a></li>
                            <li><a href=".\testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
                            <li><a href=".\contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div class="container-fluid hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <img src="images/prices1.png" class="img-responsive col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <img src="images/prices3.png" class="img-responsive col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <img src="images/test3.png" class="img-responsive col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            </div>

            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xl" data-ride="carousel">
                <!- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="images/prices1.png" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="images/prices2.png">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="images/test3.png">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <h3>Private or Party</h3>
            <p>Do you need a quick tan just for yourself or are you thinking of making it a fun event for you and your friends? <strong>A Kiss of Bronze Airbrush Tanning</strong> offers both personal tanning sessions and tanning parties!</p>
            <p>Never heard of a tanning party? You've heard of lingerie parties, cosmetics parties, jewelry parties, even tupperware parties!!!  Well now it's time to introduce <strong>TANNING PARTIES</strong>!</p>
            <p>You and a minimum of five (5), max of ten (10), friends get together, and you all get tanned in one session.  The hostess of six (6) or more people gets to <strong>tan for free</strong>!</p>
            <p><strong>Tanning parties</strong> are great for Girls Night In, Up-coming Special Occasions, Swimsuit Competitions, Pre-Holiday Tan Parties or if you just want to have some girlfriends over and treat yourselves!</p>
            <p>Wear dark, loose fitting clothes (ie. tracksuit, sweats). You may want to bring a bathrobe or swim suit cover-up to wear after your <strong>airbrush tan</strong> while you're drying.</p>
            <p>To all those ladies who are uncomfortable about your figure, don't worry!  Discuss your requirements beforehand whether you want to wear a bikini, swimsuit or shorts.  We deal with all shapes, sizes and ages so please do not feel nervous or embarrassed.</p>
            <div style="float:right; padding-left:8px;"><img src="images/stickerbride.png" class="img-responsive"/></div>
            <p>All brides want to look radiant on the biggest and happiest day of their lives, and nothing will give you that beautiful bride glow like a sun kissed tan.  Have a trial tan a few weeks before the big day so you can judge for yourself which day after your spray tan application you feel that your tan is at its best. This gives you enough planning time to book again before the big day!</p>
            <p>**Call for special pricing.</p>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

How am I supposed to do to make the pages look exactly the same in terms of alignment of page components?
I tried the same pages on a different browser, MSEdge. Curiously, every page looks the same in terms of alignment.

Comment: "In other words, the page with fewer paragraphs is aligned left compared with the page with more paragraphs." It seems that you have answered your own question within the question.

Comment: I do not see anything different besides one version has a scroll bar that moves over the elements a bit

Comment: The only difference seems to be the scrollbar. So, the only thing you would need to do is to put `overflow-y: scroll;` in your `body` CSS selector.

Comment: Buzinas! Thanks! This works!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, there are frequently `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudoelements applied. That would be the first place to look.

Could you please throw your code sample into a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue you're having?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference seems to be the scrollbar. So, the only thing you would need to do is to put `overflow-y: scroll;` in your body CSS selector. 
---------- Buzinas

is the correct answer. Buzinas, you save my day!!!Many thx!